# Regex: match all occurrences of a pattern

Tags: regex

Is there a way to check that a string matches all occurrences of a pattern?
For it to be Valid, all must match.

My rule is:

```
E followed by any 4 digits followed by 49
```

So if if E is found then it must match that pattern otherwise invalid.

My string:

```
tel: +E12345498912345678, +498912345678, +E123449D1238912345678, tel: +E1234498912345678
```

This should fail as the first element is invalid but passes because pattern is matched elsewhere.
The other 3 elements are all valid.
How do I get it to match all occurrences whne E pattern exists?

Further to this, I need to ensure that each element has + in front.
So I guess I could do check for E, 4, digits, 49 first then check for +

Comment: What's your expected output? You mean immediate following of digits 49 after 4 digits?

Comment: The pattern could be anywhere in the string though. If I use anchors won't that mean it has to be at the start?

Comment: first one fails because 1234 was not followed by 49.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
^(\+E\d{4}49.*?(,|$)\s*)+$
```

This validates:

```
+E123449D123891234, +E123449D123891234, +E123449D123891234, +E123449D123891234
```

But not:

```
+E12345498912345678, +498912345678, +E123449D1238912345678, +E1234498912345678
```

Here you can check a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uC1qI6/2).

Comment: The second one is valid too though, +498912345678 is valid element.
The E pattern may or not be there, but if it is, needs to be valid

Comment: @En-Motion That's your example and you required it to fail.

Comment: Sorry yes, the second one is not valid. You were right. Just need to extend regex another bit for other rules

Comment: did you want to make E optional? Please update your question with valid and invalid matches.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Or better post another question, otherwise the answers will not match the question anymore and that's bad for future readers.

Comment: OK, i'll post another. And thanks for help/patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern:

```
^(\+E\d{4}49\d*($|,\s))+$
```

That validates that the entire string consists of groups of `+Exxxx49xxxx...`, separated by comma-space pairs.